# Unable to understand __toString() function OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am now learning object oriented php and i face a problem with the magic method named __toString().

There are no calls for that function. Is it similar to other magical function?

If a use it to my class then is it convert all the objects all string or not?

Code-

```
class MyClass
{
  public $prop1 = "I'm a class property!";

  public function __construct()
  {
      echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was initiated!<br />';
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
      echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was destroyed.<br />';
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
      echo "Using the toString method: ";
      return $this->getProperty();
  }

  public function setProperty($newval)
  {
      $this->prop1 = $newval;
  }

  public function getProperty()
  {
      return $this->prop1 . "<br />";
  }
}

// Create a new object
$obj = new MyClass;

// Output the object as a string
echo $obj;

// Destroy the object
unset($obj);

// Output a message at the end of the file
echo "End of file.<br />";

?>
```

The output-

`The class "MyClass" was initiated!
Using the toString method: I'm a class property!
The class "MyClass" was destroyed.
End of file.`

Comment: Have you read the documentation about the method? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: I use this website to learn and i want help to clear it that's why i as asking it here.  
[link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762)  

But i got a negative vote...  
I am disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

The magic `__toString` method is called when an object of that class is getting used as a string:

```
class Something {
    private $whatever;
    public function __construct($whatever) {
        $this->whatever = $whatever;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->whatever;
    }
}

$obj = new Something("Whatever here!");
echo "Object is $obj"; // Object is Whatever here!
```

See **[The Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)**.